# Combining minmaxscaler.partial_fit and joblib Parallel, n_samples_seen_ is not cumulate samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib

I use multiprocessing to train a sklearn minmax scaler.
I have a huge quantity of csv to take in consideration so I use `.partial_fit`.

all seem to run well but at the end when I do some inspection of my scaler I found strange thing.

Consider all my csv columns have equal row number. I train the scaler on all feature and an other one on a single column.

When I look at n_samples_seen_ I got this results:

if I run only one csv...

`xy_scaler.n_samples_seen_`  = 14609 (number of row in one csv)

`y_scaler.n_samples_seen_` = 6       (!!??)

with 2 csv...

`xy_scaler.n_samples_seen_`  = 14609

`y_scaler.n_samples_seen_` = 12

Both 2 scaller are supposed to cumulate seen samples but only `y_scaler` do it. It work for `xy_scaler` when I run a for loop without joblib Parallel.

And why `y_scaler` find only 6 samples?

I want to be sure that my scalers are trained on all csv data and not only on the last csv seen.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.preprocessing as sk
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

bd_path = 'E:/Python/Data/hydrology_forcasting/Caravan/timeseries/compil/'

min=-1
max=1
path_list=glob.glob(bd_path +'*.csv')
col_selection =[7,2,5]
label=2
xy_scaler = sk.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(min, max))
y_scaler = sk.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(min, max))
TOTAL_NUM_CORES = multiprocessing.cpu_count()


def loop_loading_train(one_csv_path, xy_scaler, y_scaler, feature_selection):
    
    data = pd.read_csv(one_csv_path, 
                    usecols=feature_selection)#,
                    #   engine='pyarrow'),
                    #   dtype_backend='pyarrow')
    
    y_scaler.partial_fit(np.array(data.iloc[:label]).reshape(-1,1))
    xy_scaler.partial_fit(data)



Parallel(n_jobs=TOTAL_NUM_CORES, backend="threading")(delayed(loop_loading_train)(filename, xy_scaler, y_scaler, col_selection) for filename in path_list)
```

Thank all for your help